# Optimize usage of SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I execute a stored procedure from C# like this:

```
medianOfProjects = db.ExeSQLParamByDateTime("usp_TaskStatistics_Median_Calculation", parameters, "@TaskTypeTableType", 1, startDate, endDate
                     unitNumberFrom, unitNumberTo, unitNumberBldgsSegsFrom, unitNumberBldgsSegsTo, unitNumberSqrFrom, unitNumberSqrTo, unitNumberWoodStoriesFrom,
                unitNumberWoodStoriesTo, currentRegionKey);
```

`ExeSQLParamByDateTime` method is too large:

```
public DataTable ExeSQLParamByDateTime(string sprocName, DataTable paramArray, string tableTypeName, int LegacyKey, DateTime startingDate, DateTime endingDate,
            int unitNumberFrom, int unitNumberTo, int BldgSegsFrom, int BldgSegsFromTo, int SquareFootageFrom, int SquareFootageTo, int WoodStoriesFrom,
            int WoodStoriesTo, int StatusKey)
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocName, this.dbconn);

   var startDate = startingDate.Date;
   var endDate = endingDate.Date;

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(tableTypeName, SqlDbType.Structured));
   cmd.Parameters[tableTypeName].Value = paramArray;

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LegacyKey", SqlDbType.Int));
   cmd.Parameters["@LegacyKey"].Value = LegacyKey;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
   cmd.Parameters["@StartingDate"].Value = startDate;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
   cmd.Parameters["@EndingDate"].Value = endDate;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UnitNumberFrom", SqlDbType.Int));
   cmd.Parameters["@UnitNumberFrom"].Value = unitNumberFrom;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UnitNumberTo", SqlDbType.Int));
   cmd.Parameters["@UnitNumberTo"].Value = unitNumberTo;

   //etc
   //etc
}
```

There is no way to optimize this? I just checking for good practices, as you can see I send param DataTable to execute sql `TableType` and in addition send parameters, but I don't found anything similar like this. Help is appreciated. regards

Comment: What do you mean by optimise. be specific

Comment: I think he just means reduce the amount of code. Two lines per parameter (3 including the white space) + a lot of parameters can get tedious.

Comment: If you use a micro ORM like Dapper or PetaPoco it will reduce a fair amount of this kind of boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DataTable ExeSQLParamByDateTime(string sprocName, DataTable paramArray, string tableTypeName, int LegacyKey, DateTime startingDate, DateTime endingDate,
        int unitNumberFrom, int unitNumberTo, int BldgSegsFrom, int BldgSegsFromTo, int SquareFootageFrom, int SquareFootageTo, int WoodStoriesFrom,
        int WoodStoriesTo, int StatusKey
        )
{
    var result = new DataTable();

    //Not good to re-use the same connection object.
    // ADO.Net is designed to use connection pooling, which means you want a new connection each time.
    // Instead, just re-use the connection string
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(this.dbconn.ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocName, cn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //only need to do this once

        //Most parameters can get down to a single line
        cmd.Parameters.Add(tableTypeName, SqlDbType.Structured).Value = paramArray;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LegacyKey", SqlDbType.Int).Value = LegacyKey;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startingDate.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endingDate.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitNumberFrom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = unitNumberFrom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitNumberTo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = unitNumberTo;
        //etc
        //etc

        //you can also handle parameters with size scopes this way:
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FakeParam", SqlDbType.Decimal, 5, 2).Value = 123.45;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AlsoFake", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = "Hello World";

        cn.Open(); // wait as long as possible to open the connection
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            result.Load(rdr);
            rdr.Close();
        }
    } //using block handles closing the connection, even if an exception is thrown
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `using` eliminates the need for closing the reader. `Dispose` will close reader eventually.

Comment: `The documentation for SqlDataReader doesn't make the same claim for the reader.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb161019.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 states `The base implementation of this method calls the Close method if disposing is set to true.`

Comment: Well that's a fairly recent change :) Welcome to programming, where everything you think you know is just a snapshot of how things were at some point in the past.